# Append rows for each value of dictionary with duplicated key in next column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Unfortunately I'm struggling with following plan:

I scraped a large dictionary with usernames as keys and the keys' Instagram followers as their values.

That looks like this e.g.:

```
dict = {
"User1": ['Follower_A', 'Follower_B', 'Follower_C', 'Follower_D', 'Follower_E', 'Follower_F', 'Follower_G'],
"User2": ['Follower_Z', 'Follower_D', 'Follower_V', 'Follower_E' 'Follower_O'],
"User3": ['Follower_P', 'Follower_Q'],
"User4": ['Follower_M', 'Follower_A', 'Follower_Z', 'Follower_P' 'Follower_L'],
.
.
.,
"UserX": ['Follower_Z', 'Follower_D', 'Follower_V', 'Follower_E' 'Follower_O','Follower_Q']}
```

In order to create a network I need to have a data frame that looks like this:

```
User    Follower
0   User1   Follower_A
1   User1   Follower_B
2   User1   Follower_C
3   User1   Follower_D
4   User1   Follower_E
5   User1   Follower_F
6   User1   Follower_G
7   User2   Follower_Z
8   User2   Follower_D
9   User2   Follower_V
10  User2   Follower_E
11  User2   Follower_O
12  User3   Follower_P
13  User3   Follower_Q
```

Does anybody have an idea to create this in an efficient way?
All my tries didn't work out...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us your best try and we can start from there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flattening for tuples with `DataFrame` contructor.

Also dont use variable name `dict`, because it is python code reserved word.

```
d = {
"User1": ['Follower_A', 'Follower_B', 'Follower_C', 'Follower_D', 'Follower_E', 'Follower_F', 'Follower_G'],
"User2": ['Follower_Z', 'Follower_D', 'Follower_V', 'Follower_E', 'Follower_O'],
"User3": ['Follower_P', 'Follower_Q'],
"User4": ['Follower_M', 'Follower_A', 'Follower_Z', 'Follower_P', 'Follower_L'],
"UserX": ['Follower_Z', 'Follower_D', 'Follower_V', 'Follower_E', 'Follower_O','Follower_Q']}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(oldk, k) for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv], 
                   columns=['User','Follower'])
print (df)
     User    Follower
0   User1  Follower_A
1   User1  Follower_B
2   User1  Follower_C
3   User1  Follower_D
4   User1  Follower_E
5   User1  Follower_F
6   User1  Follower_G
7   User2  Follower_Z
8   User2  Follower_D
9   User2  Follower_V
10  User2  Follower_E
11  User2  Follower_O
12  User3  Follower_P
13  User3  Follower_Q
14  User4  Follower_M
15  User4  Follower_A
16  User4  Follower_Z
17  User4  Follower_P
18  User4  Follower_L
19  UserX  Follower_Z
20  UserX  Follower_D
21  UserX  Follower_V
22  UserX  Follower_E
23  UserX  Follower_O
24  UserX  Follower_Q
```

Comment: Perfect, nice idea!
Thank you very much!!